# Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'WebServiceWrapper.ItemMaster'

Tags: c#

I am getting an invalid cast error from 'System.String' to 'WebServiceWrapper.ItemMaster'. This is my code:

```
public class ItemMaster
{
    public static ItemMaster loadFromReader(string oReader)
    {
        ItemMaster i = (ItemMaster)Convert.ChangeType(oReader, typeof(ItemMaster));
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you repost your example code as what is there makes no sense. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you think that a ChangeType from String to ItemMaster would work?

Comment: here the written type is ItemMaster

Answer (score 0):

You can only cast from `string` to `ItemMaster` if there is an explicit operator implemented on ItemMaster, which does the work.

See the example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Edit: implicit -> explicit, updated link.

Comment: The cast is only required if there is an *explicit* operator implemented.  If the operator were implicit, the cast would not even be necessary.

Comment: Of course you are right :) Misread the question's demand of usage.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points...

You're talking about readers and strings as if they're interchangeable... they're not.

You are casting after changing the type... this is redundant.

You can't cast `ItemMaster` to `string` unless `ItemMaster` has an explicit cast defined.

Do you simply want `ItemMaster.ToString()`?

Comment: I want to cast from string to ItemMaster, not the other way

Comment: Right, I got that backward, but it's still redundant... you're calling `ChangeType` to change the string to an `ItemMaster`, then casting the result as an `ItemMaster`.  And you still need an implicit cast for string defined on `ItemMaster`

Comment: I agree the rest of Pradeep's code has problems, but the explicit cast after calling ChangeType is not one of them.  ChangeType returns **object**; why *wouldn't* you need an explicit cast?